# How do I replace a text with a picture?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://dl.dg-site.com/functionmentes/

Here I have a slider that has 2 tabs ... their name is "TAB1" and "tab2"

I want to replace the text with different images on each tab

This is the code CSS:

```
.dnd-tabs.dnd-tabs-style1 .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active a
{
    color: #093d71;
    backgroun-image:url("images/dl-products-icons5.jpg");
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
}
```

Unfortunately my code is not working ... can you help me please?

Comment: Could you post hour Html too?

Comment: And add JavaScript (if you use js..)

Comment: Right away, I can see you misspelled `background-image`.

Comment: Your `background-image` styles don't appear in the admin tools inspector.  That said, you have a typo: `backgroun-image`.

Comment: No image exists on that site at that path.

Comment: images exist...this is the link http://dl.dg-site.com/wp-content/themes/aeron/images/

Answer (score 0):

Replacing text won't work, but you can make the text transparent, like this:

```
color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Then you can set a background image to the element to show the image. You probably have found this out, but you have a typo in your code. `backgroun-image` should be `background-image` (missing a 'd').